# Mediaplayer play 2 songs

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

**Unable to switch between songs**

Totally new to this thing.

> I have two buttons in my android app.
>
> I'd like to play 2 songs using MediaPlayer.
>
> When I play one button, everything is fine, but when I start the 2nd
>   button, the first song is still playing. How do I stop that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to end the 1st song and then start the 2nd song. So for each button, do something like this. You need to check first to see if the music is playing, and if it is, end it. Then start your new song

```
    if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.reset();
        mPlayer.release();    
    }

   mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Song1); //then song2 
   mPlayer.start();
```